# Spring MVC Access Service class from a Cron Method annotated with @Scheduled

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cron

I have a working cron method but it gives me a null java.lang.NullPointerException on my service class:

```
public class CronTask {



    private JpassatemposService jpassatemposService;
    @Autowired(required=true)
    @Qualifier(value="jpassatemposService")
    public void setJpassatemposService(JpassatemposService concs){
        this.jpassatemposService = concs;
    }




    @Autowired
    private ServletContext sCtx;





  //    @Scheduled(cron ="46 11 * * * ?")
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=30000)
    public void sendCodPendentes(){

        System.out.println("Start :: "+ new Date());
        try {
            System.out.println("TRY "+ new Date());

            List<Jpassatempos> aTerminar = this.jpassatemposService.listJpassatempos24H();
            System.out.println("24 "+ new Date());
            List<Jpassatempos> enviados = this.jenviocodpendentesService.listJenviocodpendentes24H("CodPendentes24");
            System.out.println("Enviados "+ new Date());
            List<Jpassatempos> resultado = new ArrayList<Jpassatempos>();

            .....
```

Any Help is appreciated

Cron xml:

```
    <?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

    <task:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="cronTask" class="com.setelog.spring.CronTask"></bean>
</beans>
```

My full config xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd   
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.setelog.spring" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.setelog.spring.cron" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>

        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
                <bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceWebArgumentResolver" />
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>

    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <mvc:interceptors>
           <bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="com.setelog.spring.businessrules.Interceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:config.properties</value>            
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="staticMethod" value="com.setelog.spring.dao.UserDetailsDaoImpl.setEmails_Blocked"/>
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>${emails_blocked}</value>
            </list>
       </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="staticMethod" value="com.setelog.spring.handler.LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider.setEmails_Help"/>
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>${emails_help}</value>
            </list>
       </property>
    </bean>


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


 <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

         <!-- setting maximum upload size -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />

    </bean>




    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="pt" />
        <property name="cookieName" value="myAppLocaleCookie"></property>
        <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="3600"></property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="locale" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

</beans>
```

The output i get is as follows:

Start :: Tue Dec 01 12:51:19 GMT 2015
TRY Tue Dec 01 12:51:19 GMT 2015
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: what is the error? do you face any errors? @Scheduled is from Quartz??

Comment: The error is NullPointerException on "jpassatemposService" . Scheduled is from :org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled

Comment: configuration please?

Comment: http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/23/4-ways-to-schedule-tasks-in-spring-3-scheduled-example/

Comment: My Cron task is working. I get the following output: Start :: Tue Dec 01 12:22:12 GMT 2015
java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: When you say "The error is NullPointerException on 'jpassatemposService'", do you mean that jpassatemposService is null, so you get the NullPointerException when you attempt to call jpassatemposService.listJpassatempos24H()? Or does that method get called successfully, and then the NullPointerException is thrown within that method?

Comment: Im sure jpassatemposService is null. But only in this Cron Class. In all my controllers it is working fine

Comment: Also, when  you say "My Cron task is working", do you mean that it's being correctly triggered by Spring's scheduling mechanism? Or are you running it via a unit test or something else?

Comment: It is triggered correctly every 30 seconds because it's outputing   
Start :: Tue Dec 01 12:22:12 GMT 2015 java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Do you know if your ServletContext is being autowired? It sounds like there's an issue in your spring config that's stopping the CronTask bean's properties from being autowired, but from the config here I can't see why that would be.

Comment: post the full configuration

Comment: I update my question with the full config

Comment: have you added these in your configuration or alreayd exists ? xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd

Comment: It's in the cron.xml. I re-edited my question

Comment: Not sure why this would be the case, but I'd be interested if it makes a difference if you move the `<bean id="cronTask" class="com.setelog.spring.CronTask"></bean>` into the main config XML file, rather than the cron one? I'm just thinking this because you say that the components configured in the main file seem to be getting the autowired `JpassotemposService` correctly.

Comment: I can't do that because i would need the schemas Bilbo Baggings mentioned and that would mess up my config...
I tried annotating this class as a controller but it also didn't work, it must have something to do with @Scheduled

Comment: I'd be surprised if it's to do with the `@Scheduled` annotation, the fact that the autowired properties are `null` suggests to me that the problem is in the autowiring. The fact that Spring isn't reporting an error on startup about the autowiring says to me that it's not attempting to do it. I haven't used XML config for a while, so I'm guessing, but could it be that you're defining the `<bean>` in XML, but not specifying any properties? You say that annotating it as a `@Controller` didn't work - what happened?

Comment: If i annotate as a Controller its the same thing no change.
For instance if i take all the code from this method and simply put it in a controller and call that page, everything works fine

Comment: What happens if you remove the `<bean>` definition from the XML, and annotate this class as `@Component`?

Comment: If i remove that definition it won't trigger the cron task

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96695/discussion-between-daveydavedave-and-kunal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a discussion in the chat with @Kunal, we established that the problem was with the following XML configuration:

```
<bean id="cronTask" class="com.setelog.spring.CronTask"></bean>
```

The two services referred to in the code were being created in the XML config, and so needed to be set directly in this `<bean>` definition, so the following solution worked:

```
<bean id="cronTask" class="com.setelog.spring.CronTask"> 
  <property name="jpassatemposService" ref="jpassatemposService"/> 
  <property name="jenviocodpendentesService" ref="jenviocodpendentesService"/> 
</bean>
```

Posting here for others who might find this with the same issue in the future.